# Javascript threejs multi scene and mouse event

Tags: three.js

I am using Threejs for container cargo loading interactive program. Since my cargo loading plan is layer by layer for one container. So I want to divide the browser into multiple scenes. Each scene represents one layer. Every layer has its own arrangement of cargo boxes and operator could make some adjustment. And all cargo boxes are cubic type of shape.

My codes are based on example, webgl_interactive_cubes_ortho.html (r82), and I does not so many cubes in the example so I modify the code example a little bit.

The example codes works but only has one scene with Viewport. Since I want to divide browser vertically, so I begin to divide the height into 2 scenes. Then even I just devided Viewport into 2, see Render method in the script, Then I could not catch object selected in mouse down event.

What I believe is because of mouse click and 3D scene transform calculation. Anyway, in my case, I just want to select the object and drag and drop. Anyone could help me to make the object selected and can make drag and drop?

/1/

```
//var height = renderer.domElement.height/2; //only want to divide into two layers
```

/2/

```js
   var container, stats;
   var camera, scene, scene2, raycaster, renderer;
   var cameras =[];
   var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED,SELECTED;
   var radius = 500, theta = 0;
   var offset = new THREE.Vector3();
   var frustumSize = 1000;
   var cubesL0=[], cubesL1=[];
            var plane = new THREE.Plane();
            var intersection = new THREE.Vector3(); 
            var scenes =[];
            var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
   
   init();
   animate();
   function init() {
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
    info.style.position = 'absolute';
    info.style.top = '10px';
    info.style.width = '100%';
    info.style.textAlign = 'center';
    info.innerHTML = '<a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> webgl - interactive cubes';
    container.appendChild( info );
    
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( frustumSize * aspect / - 2, frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize /2 ,  frustumSize / -2, 1, 1000 );
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
    
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 150, 150, 150 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ) {
     var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x000fff } ) );
     if(i==0){
      object.position.x = - 100;
      object.position.y = - 100;
      object.position.z = - 100;
        }else{
         object.position.x = 200;
      object.position.y = -359;
      object.position.z = -50;
        }
     scene.add( object );
     scenes.push(scene);
     cubesL0.push(object);
    }

    
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.sortObjects = false;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    stats = new Stats();
    container.appendChild( stats.dom );

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
   }
   function onWindowResize() {
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.left   = - frustumSize * aspect / 2;
    camera.right  =   frustumSize * aspect / 2;
    camera.top    =   frustumSize / 2;
    camera.bottom = - frustumSize / 2;
  
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   }
   
   function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = (- ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);       
                console.log("mouse x:"+mouse.x+", mouse y:"+mouse.y);

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
     if ( SELECTED ) {
     if ( raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( plane, intersection ) ) {
      SELECTED.position.copy( intersection.sub( offset ) );
     }
     return;
    }
 
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( cubesL0 );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
     console.log(" there is object going to move");
     if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
      if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
      INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
      INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();

      plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(
       camera.getWorldDirection( plane.normal ),
       INTERSECTED.position );
     }
     container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
     if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
     INTERSECTED = null;
     container.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
   }

  
   function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( cubesL0 );
        
                var getTarget = true;
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
     if ( raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( plane, intersection ) ) {
      offset.copy( intersection ).sub( SELECTED.position );
     }
     container.style.cursor = 'move';
    }
      }


   function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();            
    console.log(" in mouse up event ");
    if ( INTERSECTED ) {
     SELECTED = null;
    }
    container.style.cursor = 'auto';
   }

   //
   function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    stats.update();
   }

   function render() {  
                
                var width  = renderer.domElement.width;
    var height = renderer.domElement.height;   
    //var height = renderer.domElement.height/2; //only want to divide into two layers
    var left   = 0;
    var bottom = 0;
    renderer.setViewport( left, bottom, width, height );
    renderer.setScissor( left, bottom, width, height );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
   }
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>three.js webgl - interactive cubes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   body {
    font-family: Monospace;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Finally I got it working. The question is actually how mouse event works when setViewport uses only half window.innerHeight. I could actually share it. But do not know which way is proper. Attached codes or what?

Comment: Hello, would it be possible to attach the code?;)